# Why do I leak exactly two handles when calling CreateProcess multiple times or just once?

Tags: c++, windows, handle, createprocess, resource-leak

According to `GetProcessHandleCount` I'm losing two handles when calling `CreateProcess`. Please look at the following minimal example, which will create one child-process. Before creating the child-process, the number of handles are examined. Then the child-process handles returned in the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` structure are closed, and then the handles are counted again. I get a difference of `2` handles - has anyone an idea why?

Also interesting: If I create multiple child-processes within the for-loop in the sample below, I also "leak" exactly two handles.

Edit: Please note that in the StartupInformation Structure no handles are returned, so there is nothing to close there.

Can someone explain to me this difference of two handles?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::wstring commandLine = L"C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";

    BOOL closedHT = FALSE;
    BOOL closedHP = FALSE;
    BOOL createdProcess = FALSE;

    // Count handles before creating child processes:
    HANDLE hCurrent = GetCurrentProcess();
    DWORD hCountBefore = 0;
    ::GetProcessHandleCount(hCurrent, &hCountBefore);

    // Create one child-processes:
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
        ::ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, sizeof(startupInfo));

        PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo;
        ::ZeroMemory(&procInfo, sizeof(procInfo));

        createdProcess = ::CreateProcess(NULL, (LPWSTR)commandLine.c_str(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &procInfo);
        closedHP = ::CloseHandle(procInfo.hProcess);
        closedHT = ::CloseHandle(procInfo.hThread);
    }

    // And calculate the difference of handles:
    DWORD hCountAfter = 0;
    ::GetProcessHandleCount(hCurrent, &hCountAfter);
    DWORD diff = hCountAfter - hCountBefore;

    if (createdProcess && closedHP && closedHT && diff != 0)
    {
        std::wcout << L"lost handles??: " << diff << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::wcout << L"Nothing got lost" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Clearly `CreateProcess` causes some on-demand handles to be opened. As long as the handle count doesn't keep increasing, it's not really a leak.

Comment: I'd guess that CreateProcess opens a dll (or 2), which isn't closed.

Comment: @UKMonkey: Thats it! It will load 'apphelp.dll', which will open two handles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UKMonkey is right, it will load `apphelp.dll` which will open two handles:

See the following two screenshots, showing the dlls and handles loaded / opened:

[image: DDLs and handles before calling CreateProcess]

[image: DLLS and handles after calling CreateProcess]

Loading the dll itself by calling `LoadLibrary` will open the handle to the `SESSION MANAGER`, calling `CreateProcess` the first time will open the handle to `Custom Locale`.